# Can I match * in a regex backwards lookup?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex:

```
\w+(?<=\*)(\w+)?
```

Tested against this string:

```
this is a *pick this that
```

This doesn't match anything, but simply substituting the * for a regular letter works great:

```
\w+(?<=X)(\w+)?
this is a Xpick this that
```

Matches and captures "pick" as desired.  Are wildcards not permitted in backwards lookups?

(The * in the regex is properly escaped in my language (Scala): `val reg = """\w+(?<=\*)(\w+)?""".r`)

Comment: It would be better to explain what you're trying to achieve instead of how you're trying to do it. Are you trying to capture the word that comes right after the `*` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the asterisk into a character class, where it would not require any special escaping:

```
val reg = "\w+(?<=[*])(\w+)?".r
```

Comment: `\w+(?<=[*])` will never match. You match a word character, and then lookbehind at that same letter, to check if it is an asterisk.